# Make android cut/copy/paste bar overlap other views

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar

I'm not using an action bar in my app, so when the cut/copy/paste bar is shown at the top of the screen it pushes all the other views down. Is it possible for it to instead overlap the other views and not move them? TIA

Comment: What kind of layout are you using? If it's a RelativeLayout, you could probably just position it relative to the bottom of the screen (or wherever) without positioning it based on anything else. Then just flip the visibility when you need it, and it should technically overlap without interfering with anything else

Comment: I'm using a LinearLayout, although just tried a RelativeLayout and it didn't work either, but I'm not sure on the best way to position it at the bottom of the screen? Also what do you mean by flip the visibility when I need it? Thanks

Comment: To align to the bottom, you should set the RelativeLayout parameter alignParentBottom="true" as for the visibility, you can change that through code: findViewById(R.id.yourViewsID).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); or View.Visible, depending on when you want the view displayed. Just make sure the view is only aligned with its parent and not other child views, else it will not overlap properly and items may realign themselves.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Then something in your code isn't set up correctly